# Validar usuario y contraseña php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo problemas para validar y crear una sesión con php y mysql, los datos del form coinciden con los de mi DB

```html
<?php
session_start();

$nombre = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

  require_once 'conexion.php';
  $conn = dbConnect();
 

$consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM sesion WHERE user = '$nombre' AND pass = '$password'");  

if(!$consulta){ 
 echo "Usuario no existe " . $nombre . " " . $password. " o hubo un error " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
} 
else{ 
print "Bienvenido"; 
} 

?>
```

[image: phpmyadmin]

Os dejo el archivo conexion.php donde abro la conexion con la bd

```html
<?php
function dbConnect (){
  $conn = null;
  $host = 'Localhost';
  $db =  'db_name';
  $user = 'db_user';
  $pwd =  'db_pass';
 try {
     $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);

 }
 catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo '<p>Error al conectar a la base de datos</p>';
     exit;
 }
 return $conn;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Que error te sale ? Estas seguro que los datos que traes de login, coinciden exactamente con tus datos de la BD?

Comment: Un pequeño fallo que veo es que tu `mysqli_query` le falta el parámetro de tu conexión. debería ser así : `mysqli_query ($tuconexion, "SELECT * FROM sesion WHERE user = '$nombre' AND pass = '$password'");`

Comment: Estoy seguro que los datos son correctos pues en el hago un echo con la var nombre y usuario y coinciden. ¿Como puedo hacer un echo mostrando el error???

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error haciendo esto: `if(!$consulta){ 
    echo "Usuario no existe " . $nombre . " " . $password. " O hubo un error ".mysqli_error($mysqli);` Aquí se supone que `$mysqli` es tu objeto de conexión. De todos modos, como ha dicho @D.Bulten, te falta pasar la conexión a la función `query`. Una vez resuelto eso, considera blindar tu código contra ataques de Inyección SQL.

Comment: @Tefef ¿Has probado lo que te he comentado? Para lanzar el error podrías añadir: `printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($tuconexion));` donde usuario no existe.

Comment: He probado con  $conn = dbConnect();
$consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM sesion WHERE user = '$nombre' AND pass = '$password'"); Y no funciona. También he hecho un echo a mysqli_error y no muestra el error

Comment: Podrías añadir tu `conexion.php` y la funcion `dbConnect()` ya que la sentencia esta correcta así.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con el archivo conexion.php donde abro conexion con la db

Comment: Para facilitar que la respuesta sea rapida y de calidad, te recomiendo que incluyas en tu pregunta todos los archivos que tienen que ver, ya que el problema podría incluso venir del html

Comment: Allí está el fallo, no puedes crear una conexión en `PDO` y luego usar `mysqli_query`, estas mesclando dos estilos. Deberías o cambiar la conexión a `MySQLi` o tus sentencias a `PDO`. Podrías crear tu conexión de la siguiente manera `$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "password", "base_datos");`

Comment: @D.Bulten le recomendaría que mejor se quede con PDO, es muy superior a mysqli. Tefef, si te decides por PDO podría aportar una respuesta basada en esa opción, dándole además seguridad al código contra inyección SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy de acuerdo contigo, su código es vunerable ante inyección `SQL`. Para ello deberia usar mejor `PDO` o `MySQLi::prepare`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Decir que PDO es muy superior a MySQLi es cuanto menos dudoso, PDO hace algunas cosas muy bien o mas fáciles. Pero decir que es muy superior... es discutible.

Comment: @Xerif es superior por varios motivos: no solo por la facilidad con que permite hacer ciertas cosas , porque mysqli es dependiente en algunos casos de otros drivers , porque puedes mapear resultados a clases, porque pasar de un manejador de base de datos a otro con PDO es casi imperceptible... Eso y otras cosas lo hacen muy superior a mysqli.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo único relevante de tu comentario es que puedes utilizar multiples BD con PDO. Mysqlnd es nativo php desde PHP>=5.3 la antigua Biblioteca Cliente de MySQL carece de soporte desde hace años en php, tanto para MySQLi como PDO la recomendación es el driver Mysqlnd. 'porque puedes mapear resultados a clases', esto tambien es posible en MySQLi, vease `fetch_object`

Comment: @Xerif, si quieres puedes leer [este artículo](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison) del único [usuario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) que tiene medalla de oro en `pdo, mysqli, sql-injection` en Stackvorflow en inglés. Creo que los argumentos expuestos son válidos para concluir que PDO es con ventaja mejor que mysqli.

Comment: @A.Cedano Voy a echarle un vistazo, pero me hace gracia que la primera frase indique que una no es peor que la otra.

Comment: @A.Cedano de lo que se desprende el articulo es que PDO es mas usable, no mejor ni peor, como husted afirma.

Comment: @Xerif más *usable*, que yo interpreto por más *mejor*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revisemos tu código, he incluido la explicación en los comentarios del mismo.

```
<?php
session_start();

$nombre = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

require_once 'conexion.php';
// se asume conexion en $conn incluido desde conexion.php, ejemlo:
// $conn= mysqli_connect("server", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");

// añadiría un limit 1 a la consulta pues solo esperamos un registro
$consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM sesion WHERE user = '$nombre' AND pass = '$password'");  

// esto válida si la consulta se ejecuto correctamente o no
// pero en ningún caso válida si devolvió algún registro
if(!$consulta){ 
    // echo "Usuario no existe " . $nombre . " " . $password. " o hubo un error " . 
    echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
    // si la consulta falla es bueno evitar que el código se siga ejecutando
    exit;
} 
// este else sobra
//else { 
    //print "Bienvenido"; 
//} 

// validemos pues si se obtuvieron resultados 
// Obtenemos los resultados con mysqli_fetch_assoc
// si no hay resultados devolverá NULL que al convertir a boleano para ser evaluado en el if será FALSE
if($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
    // el usuario y la pwd son correctas
} else {
    // Usuario incorrecto o no existe
}


?>
```

En cualquier caso decir que este código es vulnerable a inyección SQL, puede ver más sobre el tema aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

la solucion efectivamente era la conexión a la base de datos. He excluido mi archivo de conexion en PDO y he hecho la conexion directamente en la variable $conn de la siguiente manera. Cambiaré todas mis conexiones a PDO para mayor seguridad

```html
<?php
session_start();

$nombre = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$conn = new mysqli("Localhost", "db_user", "db_pass", "db_name");
 

$consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM sesion WHERE user = '$nombre' AND pass = '$password' LIMIT 1");  

if(!$consulta){ 
    header("location: index.php");
    echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
   
} 



if($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
    header("location: redireccionar.php");
} else {
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: No entiendo esta resuesta, considero que es el mismo código que yo te puse y si es así y te ayudo a resolver el problema, es mejor que marques la primera respuesta en la que el código está explicado como aceptada para que otros usuarios con el mismo problema les pueda servir. En cuanto a lo que comentas en esta respuesta, no aporta nada a la solución directamente, por lo que lo más adecuado sería hacerlo en los comentarios. Un saludo.

Comment: En la respuesta que publicaste, no aparece la conexion a la base de datos, en mi respuesta la especifico en la variable $conn

Comment: La forma de conexión  es exactamente la misma, eso no varia en nada, por eso deje comentario de que se asume conexion en `$conn`, pero lo añado por completarlo. Un saludo